# pyqt qlabel displays only first char of string

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qlabel

I want to display some string in QLabel on button click but my code only shows first char of the string. I am using following code for this

```
class UITesterWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UITesterWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.test2 = QPushButton("Test1", self)
        self.test2.setGeometry(10, 360, 200, 30)
        self.test2.setStyleSheet("font: bold 12pt Courier")

        self.emailIDIN = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.emailIDIN.setStyleSheet("font: bold 18pt Courier") 
        self.emailIDIN.move(420, 170)

class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 450)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.testerEvent()

    def testerEvent(self):
        self.SecondWindow = UITesterWindow(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.SecondWindow)

        self.SecondWindow.test2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.test3("data"))

        self.show()

    def test3(self, data):
        self.SecondWindow.emailIDIN.setText("hello")
```

In above code I want to set qlable as "hello" but only 'h' is displayed. What is the reason for this and how can I correct my code?

Comment: does it fit to window? it seems you moved it far close to the edge

Comment: Yes it fit to window

Comment: Just make the label wider: `self.emailIDIN.setGeometry(420, 170, 200, 30)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because the size of the `QLabel` initially depends on the content of the text, and since this empty initially only takes the necessary width for a letter, the solution is to call the method [`adjustSize()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#adjustSize).

```
def test3(self, data):
    self.SecondWindow.emailIDIN.setText("hello")
    self.SecondWindow.emailIDIN.adjustSize()
```

*Note: It is not advisable to have a variable that is named as a class since it can cause errors.*